# Codeigniter facebook authentication issue

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am using sdk 5.5 for facebook login

After login on facebook page, on redirect url i am here is a check for user authentication.

```
if ($this->facebook->is_authenticated())
```

This line always returns false. I checked is_authenticated library function and found that $this->authenticate() is returning with empty access token.

All configurations and redirect url are correct. Below is facebook config code

```
$config['facebook_app_id']              = '******';
$config['facebook_app_secret']          = '***************';
$config['facebook_login_type']          = 'web';
$config['facebook_login_redirect_url']  = 'fb-login';
$config['facebook_logout_redirect_url'] = 'logout';
$config['facebook_permissions']         = array('public_profile', 'email');
$config['facebook_graph_version']       = 'v2.6';
$config['facebook_auth_on_load']        = TRUE;
```

Let me know if anyone need more information.

Comment: We need more information.

Comment: Did you got answer of this problem?

Answer (score -1):

you must load library facebook in controller or autoload.

$this->load->library('facebook');

if is_authenticated still always return false

try clear all cache cookies on your browser.

Comment: If it was a problem with loading the relevant files, then they would get an error saying that some class definition is not found, or something like that. If they can _call_ the method, then it is not a problem of embedding source files.

Comment: finaly i found problem, i clear all hystory cache etc in browser and works!